# Multiple table query using CDbCriteria on Yii

Tags: php, sql, yii, frameworks

I want to implement this query on my model using **CDbCriteria** on **search** function

this is the query

```
select t.*
from transaksi t, stock_cabang sc, cabang c
where t.id_stock_cabang = sc.id
and sc.id_cabang = c.id and c.id =1;
```

this is my function

```
public function search() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('jumlah_masuk', $this->jumlah_masuk);
    $criteria->compare('id_user', $this->id_user);
    $criteria->compare('id_stock_cabang', $this->id_stock_cabang);
    $criteria->compare('waktu', $this->waktu, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

please help Me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a sample code of using 3 tables.

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array(
            'Table1' => array('alias'=> 't1', 'together' => true, ),
            'Table2' => array('alias'=> 't2', 'together' => true, ),
        );
    $criteria->together = true;
    $UserProduct = UserProduct::model()->find($criteria);
```

Here `alias` is optional.

Few more options can be added like

```
#   GET THE FRIENDS OF CURRECT PROFILE 
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = array(
        'Relation1' => array('alias'=> 'r1', 'together' => true, 
            'select' => array('r1.user_id', 'r1.relator_id', 'relation',) ),
        'Relation2' => array('alias'=> 'r2', 'together' => true, 
            'select' => array('r2.relator_id', 'r2.user_id', 'relation',) ),
    );
    $criteria->addCondition('( r1.user_id = "'.$fId.'" OR r2.relator_id = "'.$fId.'" ) AND t.id = "'.$fId.'" AND 
    ( r1.relation != "2" AND r2.relation != "2" ) ');
    $criteria->together = true;
    $userFriends = User::model()->find($criteria);
```

Comment: Hey, now I understand what `together` property does.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i would recommend you to use relations between the models for example create a model for each table and then use an BELONGS_TO relation this can reslove your problem,

another solution may be using the [JOIN parameter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#join-detail) and joing the other tables,
some similliar solution you can find here: [Yii: working with multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814279/yii-working-with-multiple-tables)

good luck!

sorry if i have language mistakes

Comment: in that question that similar with mine only use 2 tables,but i use 3 tables...i have relation on my model too